# jboss weld CDI initilize error

Tags: jboss, weld

I can't get weld working.
Below my simple CDI test in Java SE

1) Test

```
public class RuntimeEnvironmentProducerTest { 
@Inject
    RuntimeEnvironmentProducer environment;
    public void runTest(){
        if(environment != null){ 
            System.out.println("environment ok"); 
        }else{ 
            System.out.println("environment not ok"); 
        } 
     } 
 }
```

2) Main

```
public class MainTests { 
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
           Weld weld = new Weld(); 
           WeldContainer container = weld.initialize(); 
           RuntimeEnvironmentProducerTest runtimeEnvironmentProducerTest
           = container.instance().select(RuntimeEnvironmentProducerTest.class).get();
           runtimeEnvironmentProducerTest .runTest(); 
           weld.shutdown(); 
          } 
}
```

3) Output:

```
12:28:12.939 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider  
12:28:13.024 [main] INFO  org.jboss.weld.Version - WELD-000900 1.1.13 (Final)  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap cannot be cast to org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.CDI11Bootstrap  
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:120)  
    at producersTests.MainTests.main(MainTests.java:17)
```

Can anyone give me some hints ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this problem by reordering the Maven dependencies. Put `weld-se` to the top.